# How to solve error in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have syntax error in my script.js file on line 38, here is my javascript code.
i used PHP ajax and javascript to repeat table rows.also i used html table tag to display news and i am going to make a newsletter thorugh php including mysql database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#save").click(function(){
    ajax("save");
});

$("#add_new").click(function(){
    $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");    
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");   
});

$("#cancel").click(function(){
    $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");   
});

$(".del").live("click",function(){
    ajax("delete",$(this).attr("id"));
});

function ajax(action,id){
    if(action =="save")
        data = $("#userinfo").serialize()+"&amp;action="+action;
    else if(action == "delete"){
        data = "action="+action+"&amp;item_id="+id;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php", 
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                if(action == "save"){
                    $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                        $(".table-list").append(""+response.fname+""+response.lname+""+response.email+""+response.phone+"<a id="+response.row_id+" class="del" href="#">Delete</a>");   
                        $(".table-list tr:last").effect("highlight", {
                            color: '#4BADF5'
                        }, 1000);
                    }); 
                }else if(action == "delete"){
                    var row_id = response.item_id;
                    $("a[id='"+row_id+"']").closest("tr").effect("highlight", {
                        color: '#4BADF5'
                    }, 1000);
                    $("a[id='"+row_id+"']").closest("tr").fadeOut();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(res){
            alert("Unexpected error! Try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: The syntax error is in the line

    `$(".table-list").append(""+response.fname+""+response.lname+""+response.email+""+response.phone+"<a id="+response.row_id+" class="del" href="#">Delete</a>");`, escape quotes or use single quotes

Comment: You may want to know that `.live()` has long since been deprecated is even removed from later versions of jQuery.  The delegated form of `.on()` is used to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem -> A mixture of `""`  and `''`

Solution:-

```
 $('.table-list').append(""+response.fname+""+response.lname+""+response.email+""+
    response.phone+"<a id="+response.row_id+" class='del' href='#'>Delete</a>");
```

Notice, changed `class="del" href="#"` to `class='del' href='#'` and `$(".table-list")` to `$('.table-list')` (although that's not that important).

Answer (score 0):

You can use console of developer tools in chrome and for firefox use firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Removed your errors

```
 $(".table-list").append(""+response.fname+""+response.lname+""+response.email+""+response.phone+"<a id="+response.row_id+"class="+del+"href=#>Delete</a>");
```